# Connection closed when saving blob

Tags: spring, file-upload, oracle11g, weblogic11g

I'm having a problem when uploading files on a weblogic application.

Once the fileuploader has finished saving the file, the following exception appears:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Conexión cerrada
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
at oracle.sql.BLOB.getDBAccess(BLOB.java:882)
at oracle.sql.BLOB.freeTemporary(BLOB.java:584)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler$OracleLobCreator.close(OracleLobHandler.java:412)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.SpringLobCreatorSynchronization.afterCompletion(SpringLobCreatorSynchronization.java:76)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:133)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.invokeAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:951)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:926)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:678)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:319)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy74.guardarFichero(Unknown Source)
```

At other environments this problem doesn't appear, so I think it must be some configuration on the JDBC driver but I'm not sure wich one I have to modify.

The invoking struts

```
    private void adjuntarFichero()throws Exception {
    logger.debug("uploadFileName = "+uploadFileName);       
    if (uploadFileName!=null && !uploadFileName.equals("")) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        HashMap<Long,String> ficheros = (HashMap<Long,String>)session.getAttribute("ficheros");
        if (ficheros == null) ficheros = new HashMap<Long,String>();

        Fichero file = new FicheroImpl();
        file.setNombre(uploadFileName);
        file.setFichero(getBytesFromFile(upload));
        file = gestorFichero.guardarFichero(file);

        ficheros.put(file.getId(), uploadFileName);
        session.setAttribute("ficheros", ficheros);
    }        
}
```

the error is produced inside the "guardarFichero" method, who invokes a DAO class that takes care of the saving

public abstract class gestorFichero
    extends org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport{

```
public Fichero guardarFichero (Fichero fichero){
    Debug.prec(fichero, "El fichero no puede ser nulo");
    return (Fichero)create(TRANSFORM_NONE, fichero);
}   
public java.lang.Object create(final int transform, final    com.aena.sgc.Fichero fichero)
{
    if (fichero == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fichero.create - 'fichero' can not be null");
    }
    this.getHibernateTemplate().save(fichero);
    return this.transformEntity(transform, fichero);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? I have a feeling your not handling an exception or not properly terminating the SQL connection but its hard to say without seeing it. The connection closed error is pretty generic.

Comment: I've added some more info to the question. We are using hibernate to flush the objects into the database. I think it's an issue of the jdbc configuration because We have deployed the application through various environments and this failure didn't appear until we reached this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I discovered wich was the problem.

It was related to the driver class. Originally we had the datasource configured to use the XA driver **oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource** and whenever we finished uploading a file, the exception was thrown.

Once I changed the driver to **oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver** these errors dissapeared.